# How to load an image via a file loader as background images for multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have a set of web pages and i want to set them with a background image but it must be something the client chooses through an 
so all the pages have the background image the user chooses

also i'm loading the page using a node.js and express backend.

I already tried uploading images but it doesn't persist it must stay that way even after they close the application

I expect that when you open the web page you see the background you choosed

EDIT: ok so i'm thinking about loading it from a image folder and then storing the name of the image in the database?

any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to upload the images to your server and then save the images with reference to the user [user id] that uploaded the image. So next time when that particular user opens the web page, you will have a reference to their saved images. I hope this helps.

Comment: actually there aren't users, the choice of images is in case the one using the application wishes to change it or for different applications installed on other place.

Comment: I guess in that case you can use the cookies and set the values in the cookies accordingly. This way you will be able to map the images to the one that uses the application.